# Guessing game not working coded wrong?

Tags: python

I have my line of code for a guessing game. But it tells me that: unindent does not match any outer indentation level, could you help me find other mistakes? Thanks!

```
number = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = int(raw_input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
guesses = 0
print ('this is your guess', guess)
if guess < number:
    print ('guess is low')
elif guess > number:
    print ('guess is high')
elif guess == number:
    break
```

Comment: Is that all your code? If so, what's with the `break`? You aren't inside a loop.

Comment: I suggest you use an IDE such as PyCharm to help weed out such issues. Regarding your issue, do you mix spaces and tabs, it might be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Unless this code chunk is inside some type of loop then the error is the `break` on the last line. `break` can only be used on loops and not of if/else.